# Unable to Insert correctly into the database, please help

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, dreamweaver

I am a newbie, really need your help.  I've been working on this for 2 days and can't get it to work correctly.  I have a form that I want to submit to the database "New Lead" form.  I am using the submodal feature for the customer notes.  For some reason, the data is not inserting correctly into the database, I keep getting an error which says undefined index "Notes."  Here is the code that I am using for the table form, and also the insert statement...please help!

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO Leads (First_Name, Last_Name, Address, City, `State`, Zip, Phone,   
Email, Fee, Referral_Source, Notes) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['First_Name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Last_Name'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Address'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['City'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['State'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Zip'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Phone'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Email'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Fee'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Referral_Source'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST["Notes"], "text"));


 <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="form1" target="_top" id="form1">


<table width="30%%" border="1">
<tr>
  <td>First Name:</td>
  <td><label for="First_Name"></label>
  <input type="text" name="First_Name" id="First_Name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Last Name:</td>
  <td><label for="Last_Name"></label>
  <input type="text" name="Last_Name" id="Last_Name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Address:</td>
  <td><label for="Address"></label>
  <input type="text" name="Address" id="Address" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>City:</td>
  <td><label for="City"></label>
  <input type="text" name="City" id="City" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>Zip:</td>
  <td><label for="Zip"></label>
  <input type="text" name="Zip" id="Zip" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Phone:</td>
  <td><label for="Phone"></label>
  <input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>E-Mail:</td>
  <td><label for="Email"></label>
  <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Fee:</td>
  <td><label for="Fee"></label>
  <input type="text" name="Fee" id="Fee" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Referral Source:</td>
  <td><label for="Referral_Source"></label>
  <input type="text" name="Referral_Source" id="Referral_Source" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Notes:</td>
  <td><a href="subform.php?Id=<?php echo $row_Recordset1['Id']; ?>" class="submodal"><img  
  src="Images/editnote.png" class="pencil" width="33" height="33" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
```

Comment: Show the table definition, preferably as the CREATE TABLE statement that was used to create the table.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket for your `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an input named `Notes` in your form. You should use a callback with submodal to insert a hidden element into your form before submitting.

http://code.google.com/p/submodal/wiki/UsingCallbackFunction

Comment: Excuse my lack of knowledge, I've been doing this for over a month now, where would I insert the callback feature? Thanks!

Comment: Any way you can help me with that....I have been trying to figure it out for the past few hours, no success :( Thanks...